# Reset IIS on ASP.NET site when an error occurres

Tags: asp.net, iis, error-handling

i have an ASP.NET web site that on some very rare occasions has an error that causes a lot of requests to fail. the error is caught and logged in the OnError override of my base class for all pages so i know when the error occurred.

since this error is very rare i want to reset the iis when it occurres so the site will return to function normally.

my question: on the OnError code below, how can i cause the IIS to reset?
i can run iisreset or can cause the iis to crash using something like
System.Environment.Exit(-1). what is there a preferred method to reset the iis?

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnError(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        LogException(Server.GetLastError())
        MyBase.OnError(e)
    End Sub
```

Comment: seems like you want to cut the same branch you are sitting on?? :) btw if you restart the IIS it shall show Application unavailable for the time duration the IIS is restarting and if for some reason IIS was unable to start again then ...........?? hope you should look for something else.

Comment: It might not apply to you, but when you restart IIS (or recycle an app-pool) *all* sites on that server (or app-pool) are reset which also means that all (in memory) sessions are lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as pointed out by other, you need to restart the ASP.NET application and not IIS (web server). Two ways to achieve this could be

1. To touch (modify) web.config (similar alternative is to touch/modify bin folder)
2. To ask AppDomain to unload (using [HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.unloadappdomain%28v=VS.100%29.aspx))

Check [this article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/7ea62799-d1cb-42ee-a1f2-e68b28dbe836/restart-aspnet-apps-programmatically-log-applicationend-events-and-use-web-management-logging.aspx) that discusses this approach.

I would also suggest you to consider period application pool recycling (possible from IIS configuration) as alternative. an

Comment: i already have pool recycling. if the error occurres during business hours i see the error emails i get and usually fix it fast but if the problem occurres at 2 am and the pool recycles at any time later i will only see the error in the morning and all the time in between the site will not be working. because this specific error is very rare i am not worried about the site not being available for a few seconds (much better than a site not working for hours)